Adjectives taking the place of nouns
Adjectives can, on occasion, take the place of nouns.  For example

I'm with stupid.

or

Stupid is here.

How are these examples analyzed?  Adjectives?  Nouns?  Dictionaries list "stupid" as a noun in these examples.  Is there a name for the phenomenon?
Thanks in advance.

That's not a noun; it's somebody's name, a proper noun. That's why there's no article. The grammar is different from a proper noun. As for writing, we should capitalize proper nouns. But you don't need that to know that this is a name: the grammar shows  it.
